# How to extract a number part of a field using regex_substr function?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to extract the numerical part of values in a column (varchar) if there exists a number in the value.

ColumnA has values like ABC, M365, J344, MCT etc.

I would like to check the entire value from second position and if is a number I would like to extract it, for instance,

a. M365, from 2nd position 365 is a number so I would like to return this substring.
b. M3AB, from 2nd position 3AB is not a number so I would not want to return this substring.

I tried     `regex_substr('M365', '[0-9]', 2)` but this is not how I want and it only returns what is there in the second position but not the entire substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
select regexp_substr(substr(x, 2), '^\d+$')
```

This starts matching the pattern at the second position in the string, requiring that a number start there.

Answer (score 0):

[0-9] only searches for one number. You want to know if they are all numbers, so you need the '+' operator. For more info, visit:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php

The following code should work for you.

```
regex_substr('M365', '[0-9]+', 2)
```

Comment: but if the value is like M36L, it would return 36 and ignore L. What I am saying is I want to the entire value from 2nd position only the entire value is a number